# How to retrain my Yolo model with another dataset

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8

my problem is that I have trained my Yolo model with a small dataset that contains only one of the classes I intend on training it, so my question is how can I continue its training?
I have searched but I seem to be missing the solution.
Thanks for the help